# Is there a gcc flag to allow C-style implicit pointer conversions in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm drowning in the sea of casts between `char*` and `unsigned char*`, it's just ridiculous. There has to be some way around this.

Comment: That's not C-style. It's equally invalid in C.

Comment: Not as far as I know, but their is a C++ one. ```template <typename TChar> void func(TChar* data){}```

Comment: @hvd If it was invalid in C then the compiler wouldn't make an exception to explicitly allow it.

Comment: @user697683 Compilers commonly allow code that is invalid according to the standard. You can confirm that the GCC developers agree that it is invalid C by compiling it in C mode with the `-pedantic-errors` option, which makes standard-required diagnostics a hard error.

Comment: Why are you casting so much?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious because noone can agree on what kind of char pointers to use to read and write bytes in memory.

Comment: @hvd It appears you're right. The fact still stands that in many situations it's just a huge pita.

Comment: I *hope* there's no such option. The compiler is telling you to fix the code. You should do that.

Comment: @user697683 I tend to use `char` for things that will contain human-readable strings (and , as such, may need to be used with the `str*` family of functions), and `unsigned char` for other stuff.   If you have to write a function that should accept either type, you can make it accept `void *` instead; then the only cast you need is one inside that function. (I realize this is "non-portable" however if anyone ever puts out a system where you can't alias char as unsigned char, I think a lot more things in my code would need fixing than that..)

Answer (score 3):

Yes `-fpermissive` will allow this

Comment: downvoter: other than the now-fixed type what if anything do you consider wrong with this answer?

Comment: Yes, this works for GCC, but not for Clang :-(

Comment: Is there a #pragma that can be used?  This didn't work: #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpermissive"

Answer (score 0):

No.  C++ pointers are more strongly typed than C's.  You are required to cast between pointer types outside of upcasting in C++ which can happen implicitly.  What you want is intentionally difficult in C++ to discourage people from doing so.

C allows these potentially unsafe conversions to occur silently, but if you enable warnings in gcc, the issues will be brought to your attention.
On another note: having a `char *` point to an `unsigned char` is well defined behavior, though could be error prone in the long run depending on how the memory is used.

Comment: Other than implicit conversions involving `void*`, C pointers are as strongly typed as C++ pointers. Both languages require a diagnostic for an attempt to implicitly convert an `unsigned char*` to a `char*` or vice versa. Some particular compilers may be more lax. In particular, gcc is *not* a fully conforming C compiler by default.